# i have just installed flutter android studio and dart but now when i check my emulator set up by simply running the initial code its showing errors

Tags: java, windows, flutter, dart, android-emulator

Could not open settings generic class cache for settings file 'C:\Users\LENOVO\StudioProjects\flutter_sanbox\android\settings.gradle' (C:\Users\LENOVO.gradle\caches\6.7\scripts\1fnwrr8g4rohfp291nvlxj5qe).

> BUG! exception in phase 'semantic analysis' in source unit '*BuildScript*' Unsupported class file major version 60

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 5s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the latest JDK version (version 16), try downgrading to JDK version 11 and see if that works.